# Safely check if tf.Tensor satisfies some condition

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I want to check that all the elements in `tnsr = tf.constant(...)` are greater than 3, I can `tf.reduce_all(tnsr > 3)` to get a scalar boolean tensor. If I'm using eager execution, or `@tf.function`, I can then use that as a normal `bool`:

```
@tf.function
def foo(tnsr):
    if tf.reduce_all(tnsr > 3):
        ...
```

but this [doesn't work with `autograph=False`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#__bool__). What do I do then?

Other things I've tried:

- `tf.cond` returns a `tf.Tensor` even for `true_fn=lambda: True`
- `bool(tf.reduce_all(tnsr > 3))` fails for the same reason as above

Comment: "`tf.cond` doesn't allow a `tf.Tensor` as its first argument in that case" - how so? [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) is designed specifically for this purpose, can you show an example where you cannot use it?

Comment: @jdehesa my mistake. I think the problem is that `tf.cond` returns a `tf.Tensor`, which doesn't solve my problem. edited qu

Comment: Right, but that is how `tf.cond` works, the idea is that in the `true_fn` callable you perform the operation you would do in the first part of the `if`, and in `false_fn` you do the `else` part. Maybe you could give a full small example of something you wouldn't know how to convert from `if` to `tf.cond`?

Comment: @jdehesa ok, i see what you mean, but that's not always possible. In particular, I'm defining a `__contains__` method, which takes one argument and returns `bool` (though mine sometimes returns a scalar boolean tensor). There's no way to put the `tf.cond` inside the `__contains__` method: that would have to be up to the caller